# How to close an Arrays.stream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sonarqube

I have this lines in my Springboot Application.

```
String[] profiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();

if (Arrays.stream(profiles).anyMatch(profil->"dev".equalsIgnoreCase(profil))) {
        return "login";
}
```

I use Sonarqube in order to track bugs and it tells me:

'Close this "Stream". Bug Blocker '

I would like to know if it is a false positive and why ?

Comment: What version of Sonarqube are you using?

Comment: SonarQube LTS 5.6.7

Comment: Which version of SonarJava plugin is installed in your SonarQube?